# poorly documented google datastore api returns undefined for transaction.get

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-cloud-datastore

This is an official example from datastore repository:

```
async function markDone(taskId) {
  const transaction = datastore.transaction();
  const taskKey = datastore.key(['Task', datastore.int(taskId)]);

  try {
    await transaction.run();
    const [task] = await transaction.get(taskKey);
    task.done = true;
    transaction.save({
      key: taskKey,
      data: task,
    });
    await transaction.commit();
    console.log(`Task ${taskId} updated successfully.`);
  } catch (err) {
    await transaction.rollback();
  }
}
```

When I try this code, `transaction.get` returns `[undefined]`. So this example doesn't handle the fact that the task might not exist.
And in the reference docs there is no entry for `transaction.get`.

Do I have to explicitly check the result and throw an error if it is undefined? Same is true for `datastore.get`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like the [getOrCreate](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/d5c9106f4af0fc4c1c959fa46b728192af6efc6d/samples/concepts.js#L1096-L1118) example from the [transactions concepts](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#datastore-datastore-transactional-update-nodejs) page.  It looks like the task wasn't found in Datastore.  Yes, you need to explicitly check the result of `get()` in both cases.

In your case, are you sure you saved the original task with an integral key id instead of a string key name?